# Why do people use second column of predict_proba() (i.e predict_proba(X)[:,1]) for roc_auc_score()?

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I've seen many times people use values of the second column of `predict_proba(X)`(i.e `predict_proba(X)[:,1]`) in order to find `roc_auc_score()` of binary classification model as follows:

```
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
rfc = RandomForestClassifier()
rfc.fit(X_train, y_train)

ypred = rfc.predict_proba(X_test)[:,1]
roc_auc_score(y_test, ypred)
```

Comment: Because the first column is Prob( Class 0 | Input ). [True and false positive rates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/True_positive_rate) which determine the ROC curve are defined in terms of the "positive class", i.e. Class 1.

Comment: @ChesterVonWinchester I really appreciate. It makes a lot more sense to me now.